# Input doesn't remain in parent container using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I am attempting to do is create a `div` container that contains a header and an input field. I have accomplished this, but for some reason I can't get the input to live inside of my parent container. Ideally I would love it to scale based on the size of its container. I want the header and the input to always be container within the container. So these two elements should always have a gray background behind them. I have a jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hryuopv8/1/). I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

```
<div class="front-page-container-search">
    <h3>This is the text I will have in my bubble. Yet when I shrink my screen the input moves down. </h3>
    <form>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find artist...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>



.front-page-container-search {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 18PX;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case all you need to do is remove the `height` and let the container take the default height of the contents. Specifying a fixed height does not provide you responsiveness and the contents are forced to occupy the limited height when the screen size is smaller or when resized. Letting the layout engine calculate the height for you based on the contents, ensures all the contents are rendered within the parent.

```css
.front-page-container-search {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 18PX;
    padding: 15px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page-container-search">
    <h3>This is the text I will have in my bubble. Yet when I shrink my 
         screen the input moves down. </h3>
    <form>
      <div class="input-group myform">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find artist...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Search</span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hryuopv8/2/).

My changes:

1. Removed the forced height in the css for `.front-page-container-search`
2. Added `div.clearfix` inside your styled container. (this may or may not be necessary.)

Comment: Nice job. Two questions. What is the purpose of `div.clearfix` I removed it and it seems to make no difference. Also why was a forced height giving me problems?

Comment: Just saw your update regarding the `div.clearfix`. Still curious about the forced height thing.